# Fixing file permission in AWS Bitnami WordPress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami

I installed "Bitnami WordPress" from AWS marketplace and then searched for files with "777" permission using the command: "find . -perm 777".

This is what I got.

[image: SSH screenshot (putty)]

Including others, there is a file called updateip inside the WordPress folder that's set to "777".

Should I be worried and change them to 755 or leave them as they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here. The `updateip` file is a binary file that it's used to configure the IP address in the application when booting/restarting the VM. In case you don't want it to have 777 permissions, you can modify it to 755 (it must have execution permissions).

Comment: hi, is 777 permission for that file a security risk? and what about the other 777 files ?

Comment: It's not a security risk because it's not inside the folder that Apache uses to serve the application. The other files and folders that have 777 permissions are not served by Apache either but the phpMyAdmin's ones. However, phpMyAdmin is only accessible using localhost (or when using a SSH tunnel) so there is not any security risk.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just leave it as 777. When you use the image from the AWS marketplace, they are specified set for the AWS, there might be some of the services from the AWS side that need to have 777 permission to run those command.